# MySQL: how to search as much as substrings matches in a table of millions of strings

Tags: mysql, hash, hashtable

Let's say I have this strings in a MySQL table:

```
id  |  hash
1   |  462a276e262067573e553b5f6a2b4a323e35272d3c6b6227417c4f2654
2   |  5c2670355b6e503f39427a435a423d6d4c7c5156344c336c6c244a7234
3   |  35785c5f45373c495b70522452564b6f4531792b275e40642854772764
... 
millions of records !
```

Now I have a set of substrings (6 character size), for example this:
["76e262", "435a42", "75e406", "95b705", "344c33"]

What I want is to know how many of these substrings are in each string, so the result could be:

```
id  | matches
63  | 5
34  | 5
123 | 3
153 | 3
13  | 2
9   | 1
```

How can achieve this in a fast way ?

Real numbers and sizes are:

1) Table with 100.000/200.000 hashes

2) Main Hash size: 256 bytes

3) Substring of mini-hashes:  16 of 32 each one

NOTE: I'd like to avoid the "%LIKE%" since it's 16 likes for each row, and millions rows

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using the Aho-Corasick algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

MySQL doesn't have a function for that, so you'd need to write your own or consider using a language like java or c to massage the data.

How about a different approach?

You could also consider having a shifting mechanism for your data and the check on the shifting. For example, if your key is 462a276e262067573e553b5f6a2b4a323e35272d3c6b6227417c4f2654 and you know that your hash will have 58 chars, then you would have these variations:

62a276e262067573e553b5f6a2b4a323e35272d3c6b6227417c4f26544
2a276e262067573e553b5f6a2b4a323e35272d3c6b6227417c4f265446
a276e262067573e553b5f6a2b4a323e35272d3c6b6227417c4f2654462
276e262067573e553b5f6a2b4a323e35272d3c6b6227417c4f2654462a
...

Each one of these would be in a column, every one of them would be indexed.

So your query would be simply:

Select * from table where hash like "a27e262%" or s1 like "a27e262%" ...

Note that this would be MUCH faster than LIKE "%value%" as the column is indexed and the LIKE is only checking the begins with.

There are many disadvantages to this solutions: space required for the extra columns, insertion and update time would increase because of the time calculating the shifted columns, and time required to process the result of the select. But you wouldn't need to implement the algorithm in mysql.

You could also require that the minimum length of the string being searched is 6 chars, so you won't need to shift the whole string, only to keep the first 6 digits. If a match is found then you keep looking for the next 6 digits on the next match.

Comment: "like" is exactly what I want to avoid, since like with "%" in both directions looking in text fields is tooooooooooo slow

Comment: but there's no mysql implementation for that ... (Aho-corasick)

Comment: I like that approach but ... having 64 bytes long string to compare in 256 bytes, I will need 192 strings for each hash. So, my table of hash will "increase" by 192 times to accomplish that. Or, horizontally as you described, a table with 192 columns is not very good... isn't it ?

Comment: If I have any other ideas I'll let you know. Let me know if you find a better solution.